# Where to install the import modules used in a java program?

Tags: java, javascript, linux

For a program the import headers are showing errors. From where can i download the importing packages? The import instance of the program is shown below..

```
package com.larmor.opencv.samples;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.media.Buffer;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceInfo;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceManager;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.util.BufferToImage;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

import com.larmor.opencv.MatchTemplate;
```

would this all be in the java library? Even if yes pls tell me how to install packages/modules that are not in the java library..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those classes are available in JSE, but it looks like it's also using JMF. You can download JMF from here:
[JMF Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html)

You don't install modules, you just add jars/classes to the classpath. How you do that depends on if you are using an IDE or not. This article can give you some insight on how things work:
[PATH and CLASSPATH](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Answer (score 1):

All the `java.awt` and `javax.swing` classes are part of the standard Java platform.

The `javax.media` classes are part of the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html). You'd have to download and install that separately.

The `MatchTemplate` thing seems to come from [here](http://www.larmor.com/portal/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=60).

To find where a package come from, look through the [Java SE API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) or search for the package name on Google.

You need to put the relevant JAR files to your classpath while compiling and running your application which uses these classes (except if they are classes in the standard Java platform; these will be automatically available).

Comment: the class path here means the standard java library na??